# Dash search does not show applications

Tags: 13.10, unity-dash, scopes

Since the upgrade (actually a fresh install) to 13.10, many times, when I open Dash and search for an application I only get results for files and folders. Sometimes I get some applications but not others. I haven't found a pattern to replicate the issue 100%.

If I open the application lens and search again, it works as it should. So many times, to launch an application, I have to use the super + a key combination to open the application scope instead of the simply the super key. It is annoying.

Did anyone have the same issue? I searched for bugs on launchpad but didn't find any. I didn't open a bug report yet because it is not clear how to reproduce the problem faithfully.

Even more importantly, does anyone have a solution to this issue?

Comment: Same problem here. It is extremely frustrating and has made the process of opening an application much slower. Notably this was working in 13.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found why this is happening.

I'm not sure this is a bug or a change in logic but when you search in Dash and no applications match the search, you have to clear the search box before searching for applications again.

Simply clearing the search box, waiting till the indicator stops turning and searching again "solves" or better works around the problem.